# Can I use a different passport for exiting the EU?

Tags: schengen, greece

Not sure if there are any specific laws against this, but double-checking.
I'm a dual Australian Italian citizen, and I want to get a Greek passport stamp on my exit (I like collecting stamps). I entered Italy using my Italian passport. Can I use my Australian passport on my exit? I understand the EES hasn't been implemented yet, so there shouldn't be much of an issue?

Comment: The issue is that they’re supposed to be looking for the entry stamp…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, when presented with an Australian passport, border guards are supposed to look for an entry stamp to check you haven't stayed too long in the Schengen area.

In practice, they do not always check that very carefully and even if they do, I don't see how you would risk anything more than a lecture since, as an  EU citizen your presence was legal all along. If I were a border guard, I would probably be annoyed, though.

Comment: I have a few pages worth of stamps, a lot of them EU (I entered and left on AUS passport, this time only leaving hence the question) so it might even be hard for them to find my entry even if I had entered with it! Thanks.

Comment: @mgrande465 One approach is to look for the most recent entry stamp, if they cannot find one that is less than 90 days old, it might prompt them to ask or look further. Or they might just see all the stamps and stamp your passport without looking...

Comment: Update - Just went through. He looked for the entry stamp, and couldn't find it. I gave him my Italian passport and apologised and went through with no problems. No stamp, oh well!